Exception when trying to access request body
I am trying to migrate my function app to the isolated worker model.  This requires my functions to be migrated from async to synchronous.
However, after migration I am not able to access the HttpRequest's Body member.
I need the body contents as a string.
I have tried various approaches, for example using a StreamReader.  Regardless what I do, I get System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
Using the [FromBody] approach does return correctly the json body parsed into an object.  However, when specifying [FromBody] in the function declaraion, the function fails if there is NO body.
I need the function to handle both GET and POST requests, and GET requests don't have a body, so the [FromBody] option is not viable.
All documentation I have found elegantly avoid showing how to access the request body.
Does anyone know how to get the contents of the request body in the isolated worker model case?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
